# IOS 10,What's the current syntax for JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(Unknow parameters)

Tags: ios, chat, avatar, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i am following an IOS chat tutorial, but the tutorial is a little outdated,
in the tutorial the instructor's syntax was:

```
JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(UIImage(named: "pictureNameWithoutExtention"), diameter: 30)
```

but this method has been replaced to:

```
JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(thisIsSomeCodeBlock<#T##JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory#>EndSomecodeBlock)
```

i tried below codes and some others, none of them worked:

```
JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(UIImage(named: "pictureNameWithoutExtention"), diameter: 30)

JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with image: UIImage(named:"pictureNameWithoutExtention"), diameter: 30)
```

what is the current syntax for this method? what parameters does it take?

also when i command+click i get this documentation but still don't understand:

```
/**
 *  Creates and returns a `JSQMessagesAvatarImage` object with the specified image that is
 *  cropped to a circle of the given diameter and used for the `avatarImage` and `avatarPlaceholderImage` properties
 *  of the returned `JSQMessagesAvatarImage` object. This image is then copied and has a transparent black mask applied to it, 
 *  which is used for the `avatarHighlightedImage` property of the returned `JSQMessagesAvatarImage` object.
 *
 *  @param image    An image object that represents an avatar image. This value must not be `nil`.
 *
 *  @return An initialized `JSQMessagesAvatarImage` object.
 */
open func avatarImage(with image: UIImage) -> JSQMessagesAvatarImage
```

i googled a lot about this, none of the documentation has Example or Demonstration about this method, i mean the documentations are not even written in plain english......why does everyone else seems to have no problem understand them, are there any tricks?

Comment: It's an instance function, not a class function.  You need to create an instance of the `JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory` to call the function on.

Comment: override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource? {
        return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: UIImage(named:"profileImage")!)
    }

Comment: i tried above code, still getting this compiler error:  ChatViewController.swift:204:46: 'avatarImage' produces 'JSQMessagesAvatarImage', not the expected contextual result type 'JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best example to look at is in the "JSQMessagesViewContoller" it is located in the project

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/tree/develop/SwiftExample

It has been recently updated to the Swift3. If you look at the demoConversation it is implimented in a few ways.

```
let AvatarLeonard = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory().avatarImage(withUserInitials: "DL", backgroundColor: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreen(), textColor: UIColor.white, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12))
```

This is how you would make an avatar for someone that does not have a picture. This creates a circle with initials in it and makes the image not nil.

```
// Create avatar with Placeholder Image
let AvatarJobs = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory().avatarImage(withPlaceholder: UIImage(named:"demo_avatar_jobs")!)
```

As to your question on why the documentation is so difficult to understand is that is difficult to show you everything that is possible with the library especially not knowing everyone's background or experience. So Documentation try's to outline everything that could be possible and 90% of the things you will not need it is a feature that someone added for a certain use case.

Also if a `perimeter` is optional then it does not have to be passed in the function. So it can become difficult to understand what you absolutely need and what can be omitted. This will come with time as you gain more exsperience and understand what is happening.

Now for your question on neither of the methods working that may not have to do with your function. Looking at the `chatViewController` in the example project has these lines up at the top

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize(width: kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault, height:kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault )
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize(width: kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault, height:kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault )
```

These set the size of the avatar for the CollectionViewLayout. It may seem confusing because you can pass the size of the avatar in the `JSQImageFactory` method but the collectionViewLayout handles shifting things around based on the size of other components in the view. So by adding these lines the Collection view knows to shif the message bubbles over to make room and make the avatars appear in the correct place.

I hope that I was able to communicate clear enough. If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask.  Good luck.

Comment: thank you for solving my problems, it all worked perfectly! really appreciate it.

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, seems like the function does not accept `radius` though.

```
JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: UIImage(named:"pictureNameWithoutExtention")!)
```

p.s.: it might be better if you check unwrap the optional before using the function.

Comment: override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource? { return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: UIImage(named:"profileImage")!) }

Comment: i've tried your code, still getting this compiler error: ChatViewController.swift:204:46: 'avatarImage' produces 'JSQMessagesAvatarImage', not the expected contextual result type 'JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource?'